# Submatches in string

Tags: regex, string, vim, decimal

I'm trying to find the longest number of decimals in a string.

p.e. string:

```
(3+2,44)*2,134 + (2,1 + 2,91280)*1,2
```

search:

```
,\zs\d\+
```

answer = 5 (,91280)

I know that there is a way to find submatches in a document using the substitute command
but how do I find submatches in a string?

Answer (score 2):

To get just the length of the longest sequence of decimal digits, you can combine a couple of standard functions like this:

```
:echo max(map(split(str, '\D\+'), 'strlen(v:val)'))
```

When `str` is the string `'(3+2,44)*2,134 + (2,1 + 2,91280)*1,2'` this echoes `5`.

To fetch the (first) longest match itself you could refine the expression further:

```
:echo matchstr(str, '\d\{' . max(map(split(str, '\D\+'), 'strlen(v:val)')) . '}')
```

Or simply `:echo max(split(str, '\D\+'))` does work, too.

See `:h function-list` for a lot more useful functions.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this with another string `echo max(split('(1,3999393939939+2,44)*2,13402002 + (2,1 + 2,91280)*1,2', '\D\+'))` This echoes 9 characters. A wrong answer. What did I wrong? This one does work fine `echo max(map(split(str, '\D\+'), 'strlen(v:val)'))`

Comment: Yeah, `:echo max(split(str, '\D\+'))` doesn't work with large numbers because they overflow (Vim's integers are signed 32-bit integers). The approach with `matchstr()` should always work though.

Comment: Can you please tell me a bit more what you're doing in `echo max(map(split(str, '\D\+'), 'strlen(v:val)'))` ?

Comment: Sure. `split(str, '\D\+')` splits the string on anything that is not a decimal digit. The result is a list of all the decimal number strings `['3', '2', '44', '2', ...]`. Then `map()` maps every item to its length. The result is a list of the lengths of all decimal numbers `[1, 1, 2, 1, ...]`. Finally `max()` selects the longest length in the list!

Comment: glts, your solution doesn't work. It takes also the numbers before the komma. p.e. `echo max(map(split('+1,0001+100002020,21', '\D\+'), 'strlen(v:val)'))` takes the wrong number. It takes the number before the komma (9).